# Apache ignore my .htaccess 'dontlog' option

Tags: php, apache-2.2, .htaccess

I wrote .htaccess in file dir/subdir to don't log URI requests in this particular directory. The .htaccess is actually executed by apache (if i write deny from , it works), but if the file contains only this rule:

```
   SetEnvIf Request_URI "^dir/subdir" dontlog
```

Don't work. AllowOverride All and mod_rewrite are enabled. What can be the problem?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have this in your htaccess :

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/dir/subdir(.*)$" dontlog
```

And something like this is you apache config :

```
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined env=!dontlog
```